# unit test stops at rxjs skipwhile

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

```
of({loadstatus: Loaded})
    .skipWhile(user => user.loadStatus !== Loaded)
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(user => do some stuff)
```

Why would a unit test not run the skipWhile? I.E. I set a breakpoint on the take(1) and I never reach it. The code does the thing I expect but I'm having a hard time trying to deal with what the skipWhile is doing during unit tests.

Comment: Include rxjs version in your question. Latest version uses `.pipe(skipWhile(...),...).subscribe()`

Comment: It's probably skipping the execution since the `user` is either not defined or `user.loadStatus` is not equal to `Loaded`? ‍♂️

Comment: Also, if you could share details like what your test looks like, what `Loaded` is here etc, that would be great.

Comment: We are using rxjs v6. What I'm showing here is exactly what I hard coded in place of getting data. I am thinking I need to learn more about marble testing this morning to get a test implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior stopped when I added

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/skipWhile';
```

to the imports of the component being tested.